# video streaming in android is not working

Tags: java, android, video, video-streaming

I am very new to android. I need to work with video streaming. I have never done any work with streaming. All I need to access to a url and play the video in my device ? I have followed a tutorial from which my approaches are as follows :

in my **activity_main.xml**

```
<VideoView
        android:id="@+id/myVideo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

in my **MainActivity.java**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
//        String vidAddress = "https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4";
        String vidAddress = "E:\\funny cartoon 3gp.3gp";
        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
        vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
        MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
        vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
        vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);
        vidView.start();
    }
```

both urls are not working. When running the app, it shows that can't play this video. Can anyone please help me on this please ?